# Knowing when a file has uploaded to Dropbox

Tags: iphone, file-upload, upload, dropbox

I have managed to get my app to upload to Dropbox like so:

```
  NSString *docsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];

[self.restClient uploadFile:@"ZipTest.zip" toPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@", self.dropboxFolderName] fromPath:docsPath];
```

But am now trying to verify it actually completed the upload.  I know I can check for errors but how to check for completion?

I have tried using:`- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client uploadProgress:(CGFloat)progress forFile:(NSString *)destPath from:(NSString *)srcPath {

Buut all I get is the number 1 printed even though I see on Dropbox the file has not completed the upload yet?

any ideas?

Thanks`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client uploadedFile:(NSString *)srcPath {


    NSString *filename = [[srcPath pathComponents]lastObject];

    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Uploaded File:%@",filename];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Success"
                                                   message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                                         otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];





}
```

I used this code to check file is uploaded or not and after uploading this alert will show

Comment: This is now
 - (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client uploadedFile:(NSString*)destPath from:(NSString*)srcPath metadata:(DBMetadata*)metadata